# How do I use getline with stdin?

Tags: c++

```
std::stringstream line;
getline(stdin, line);
```

Can someone explain to me why I am getting a "no matching function call to getline" error when I try to compile this?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site, now you should post a [*Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: when it is c++ then you should perhaps #include some stuff and then int main() and the like?

Answer (score 2):

C++ has no `getline` that takes a `FILE*` (`stdin`) and a `iostream` (`line`) as parameters.

Instead, you should

```
std::string line; 
if (std::getline(std::cin, line)) // ensure read succeeded
{
    std::stringstream linestream(line);
    // opperate on linestream    
}
```

where `std::cin` is a C++ IO stream associated with `stdin`.

If you absolutely MUST use `stdin` in the raw, on a POSIX-compliant system you can

```
char * line; 
size_t len; 
if (getline(&line, &len, stdin) != -1) // ensure read succeeded
{
    std::stringstream linestream(line);
    free(line); // release the buffer allocated by getline
                // must free(line). Do not delete line;
    // opperate on linestream    
}
```

You've tagged this as C++, so I recommend the former.

[Documentation for C++ `std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline)

[Documentation for POSIX `getline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)